# Using custom function VBA in custom field of pivot-table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

When I try to use custom function (written on VBA), in custom field of pivot table excel give me an error: "Element not found."

Function code:

```
Function testfunc(keks)
   testfunc = keks * 2
End Function
```

On the worksheets this little function work fine.

Comment: You can't do that with a pivot table.

Comment: @Rory, thank you. Do you know may be Power-Pivot can do that?

Comment: Not with functions written in VBA, but you can use DAX to create measures or calculated columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot-Table don't work with custom functions, only with default.